# pycurl and unescape

Tags: python, pycurl

curl_unescape doesnt seem to be in pycurl, what do i use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `urllib.quote`?

```
import urllib
print urllib.quote("some url")

some%20url
```

[here's](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) the documentation

Answer (score 2):

[curl_ unescape](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_unescape.html) 
 is an obsolete function. Use  [curl_ easy_unescape](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_unescape.html)  
 instead.

Answer (score 0):

We are planning to release new version of pycURL in a month or two. The new version would have all features of libcurl installed on your machine. -:)